# More then one UITextField keyboard dismiss on UIButton Click in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

In my class,i have more then 30 UITextField and one UIButton. When I click the uibutton i need to resign the keyboard of all uitextfield without giving resignfirstresponder to all 30 uitextfields.

My code like this

```
-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
   [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
   [txt2 resignFirstResponder];
   [txt3 resignFirstResponder];
   [txt4 resignFirstResponder];
   .
   .
   .
   [txt30 resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

I need simple way to resign UITextField keyboard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITextField *currentTextField;


- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
      currentTextField = textField;
}

-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
      [currentTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Every view has endEditing property , try simply this

```
 [[self view] endEditing:YES];
```

and let me know whether it works for you or not ..

Answer (score 0):

Then simply in the method below add

```
 - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField 
{
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      return YES;
}
```

or

in the delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)KeyboardHide
{
    [txt1 resignFirstResponder];
    ....
    ....
    [txt30 resignFirstResponder];
}


-(IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    [Self KeyboardHide];
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what he asked not to do. Plus, there's no such keyword "Self" with a capital S. Plus, it's not common to start a method name with a capital letter. If I were you, I would remove the post...